# Run a script when you go to a new page

Tags: javascript, tabs

How can I run a javascript function when the user exits my page? It's pretty much all in the title.

Comment: well you have onbeforeunload and unload. You have no idea why they fire. There should be tons of questions on here talking about this.

Comment: @epascarello unload is not what I want. unload is for when the user CLOSES my page, but I want it so when they go to another tab it fires. Also, did you downvote my page? Why did you do that?

Comment: When they go to another tab? Unclear what that means. So you have two tabs open and you want to know when they switch? That would be the page visibility api. If you want help, you need to add more substance to your question.

Comment: It's probably because you don't give us a lot to go on. There is no code for us to check, no use-case to consider and no result that is expected. Read up on [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to prevent future downvotes.

Comment: @EmielZuurbier ok

Comment: I was hoping you would have edited the question with more details by now.

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about a redirect, like a link clicked from your page (which opens in a new tab), you can use `event.preventDefault()`, run your script and then do the redirect manually.

If you're talking about detecting when a user leaves the view on the browser, like many news/blog sites do when then they pop up an annoying "Don't miss out!" or "Sign up now!" modal, you can run the [`mouseleave`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mouseleave_event) or the [`mouseout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mouseout_event) event handler for either `window` or `document.body` and your script will run when the user moves the mouse outside the boundaries of the view, whether to another window/program or to the tab bar or URL bar within the browser window